# Knitting Rmd treats non-english characters differently

Tags: r, knitr

I've tried to write reproducable example below. It is a mix of .Rmd and .r . Hopefully you can see why.

The problem I have is that non-english characters are treated differently depending on whether code is run directly in the console or when Knitted to HTML.

In the example below I create a small data.frame with characters ü and ö, write it to csv, then read it back in again.

If the writing and reading both take place inside or outside a chunk, then all is well.

But if the writing and reading take place in different places then a different encoding is used (I think).  and characters get mixed up.

This means that when reading in data I need a different encoding when compiling an .Rmd file than when working directly in R.

As far as I can see the locale is always the same, so I don't understand what's going on.

Any ideas?

### Write and read csv directly to create new datafile

```
df2 <- data.frame(Cäl1 = c(1,2), Col2 = c("ü","a")) 

write.csv(df2, file="df2.csv")

read.csv("df2.csv")

Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_ALL")
```

### Now try Knitting the whole document (just running the chunk behaves differently)

````
```{r read_inside}

read.csv("df2.csv")

Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_ALL")

```
````

### this second chunk will work because the data.frame is created inside the chunk

````
```{r write_read_inside}


df2 <- data.frame(Cäl1 = c(1,2), Col2 = c("ü","a")) 
write.csv(df2, file="df2.csv")
read.csv("df2.csv")

Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_ALL")

```
````

Session Info:

```
R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.15.0
```

Comment: I tried your examples, and could not confirm what you found (Windows 7, German). It would be good if you could post sessionInfo() (which also contains the locale), the problem might be platform-specific.

Comment: Windows is hell in terms of encoding. *nix often uses UTF-8 consistently. You can probably try to save your data with UTF-8 encoding like `write.csv(..., fileEncoding = 'UTF-8')` (not tested)

Comment: Thanks @Yihui, adding ", fileEncoding = 'UTF-8'" did fix things. It seems on my system that UTF-8 is used by default when knitting, but not otherwise. I have to convert my data files to "UTF-8 without BOM" and then make sure that UTF-8 is always being used when reading csv.

Comment: @Andrew actually the other way (more natural) to go is to use `options(encoding = 'native.enc')` in your R code, but I still recommend using UTF-8 consistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer is to guarantee UTF8 encoding, e.g. `write.csv(..., fileEncoding = 'UTF-8')`. The root problem was actually that RStudio uses UTF8 by default, but R uses the native encoding of the OS by default. We can either ask R to use UTF8 in `write.csv`, or ask RStudio to use native encoding (`options(encoding = 'native.enc')`).